# Including a remote image in ReportLab PDF

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am using a Django app in order to generate a PDF with reportlab which includes an oxxo barcode, but I get the following error:

```
Can not open resource "https://www2.oxxo.com:
```

My code is

```
p.drawImage(url,PAGE_WIDTH/2.0-120,380)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Reportlab documentation for `drawImage`](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/pdfgen.html#reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas.drawImage) -

```
drawImage(image, x, y, width=None, height=None, mask=None, preserveAspectRatio=False, anchor='c')

    Draws the image (ImageReader object or filename) as specified.

    “image” may be an image filename or an ImageReader object.
```

`image` can certainly not be an url. You can download the image in a local file and include that file's path as the value of first parameter `image`.

Comment: I try mport cStringIO
  import io
  import PIL.Image
  
  fd = urllib2.urlopen(datos['url'])
  image_file = StringIO.StringIO(fd.read())
  im = PIL.Image.open(image_file)
  print im
  p.drawImage(im,PAGE_WIDTH/2.0-80,430,150,80,mask='auto')

Comment: Please update your question with this, and what is the current output and error.

Comment: I try

mport cStringIO
  import io
  import PIL.Image
  
  fd = urllib2.urlopen(datos['url'])
  image_file = StringIO.StringIO(fd.read())
  im = PIL.Image.open(image_file)
  print im
  p.drawImage(im,PAGE_WIDTH/2.0-80,430,150,80,mask='auto')

but 
AttributeError
Exception Value: 
rfind